# How to add custom bulk actions in WordPress list tables?

Tags: php, wordpress

I am developing a plugin for that I have to black list users, so I need to be display one more dropdown item called **Black List** inside the **Bulk Actions** dropdown in the Users page, after the **Delete** option. But I'm unable to see from where these two actions are coming from and also how to black list a particular user.

My idea is to add one more field **is_blacklisted** in **user table**  as **Boolean** with default value `false` and when apply **Black List**  action it changes to  `true`. Any other thoughts?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[There's a filter](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/bulk_actions), but it's only useful to *remove* bulk actions.

From [this WPSE question, answer and comments](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/29822/12615), there's the following workaround: add a custom option to the dropdown with jQuery and hook into `admin_action_$your-action` to catch the submission.

The hook `admin_footer-$current_page` is used to print our JavaScript on a specific admin page (adjust to use in other screens).

```
add_action( 'admin_footer-users.php', 'bulk_footer_so_23541269' );
add_action( 'admin_action_black_list', 'bulk_request_so_23541269' );

function bulk_footer_so_23541269() 
{
    # global $typenow; if( $typenow != 'page' ) return; // if used on edit.php screen
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
            $('<option>').val('black_list').text('Black list')
                .appendTo("select[name='action'], select[name='action2']");
        });
    </script>
    <?php
}

function bulk_request_so_23541269() 
{
    # Array with the selected User IDs
    wp_die( '<pre>' . print_r( $_REQUEST['users'], true ) . '</pre>' ); 
    // $_REQUEST['post'] if used on edit.php screen
}
```

Your doubt about blocking a user deserves another question, but I'd start a [research here first](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?q=block%20user%20is:question).

Comment: This is great. Is there any security problem with this solution?

Comment: You can use `check_admin_referer('bulk-posts')` to check that it's coming from an admin page, see wp-admin/edit.php line 61

Answer (score 5):

Proper support with `add_filter( 'bulk_actions-screenid', 'register_my_bulk_actions' )` is arriving in Wordpress 4.7 .

Quoting the [announcement post](https://make.wordpress.org/core/2016/10/04/custom-bulk-actions/):

To add an option in the Bulk Actions dropdown HTML element, register a callback on the `bulk_actions-{screen_id}` filter that adds the new option onto the array. Replace `{screen_id}` with the ID of the admin screen to offer the bulk action on.

To add a bulk action “Email to Eric,” we could use the following code:

```
add_filter( 'bulk_actions-edit-post', 'register_my_bulk_actions' );

function register_my_bulk_actions($bulk_actions) 
{
  $bulk_actions['email_to_eric'] = __( 'Email to Eric', 'email_to_eric');
  return $bulk_actions;
}
```

To handle a bulk action form submission, register a callback on the `handle_bulk_actions-{screen_id}` filter for the corresponding screen. The filter expects the redirect URL to be modified, so be sure to modify the passed `$redirect_url`. This allows us to carry success or failure state into the next request to display a notice to the user. The other callback arguments will differ depending on the screen here to include contextually relevant data.

To add a bulk action handler for emailing the selected posts, we could use the following code:

```
add_filter( 'handle_bulk_actions-edit-post', 'my_bulk_action_handler', 10, 3 );

function my_bulk_action_handler( $redirect_to, $doaction, $post_ids ) 
{
  if ( $doaction !== 'email_to_eric' ) {
    return $redirect_to;
  }
  foreach ( $post_ids as $post_id ) {
    // Perform action for each post.
  }
  $redirect_to = add_query_arg( 'bulk_emailed_posts', count( $post_ids ),  $redirect_to );
  return $redirect_to;
}
```

Showing notices: We could use the existing notice hooks to let the user know what happened, depending on the state we set in the URL:

```
add_action( 'admin_notices', 'my_bulk_action_admin_notice' );

function my_bulk_action_admin_notice() 
{
  if ( ! empty( $_REQUEST['bulk_emailed_posts'] ) ) {
    $emailed_count = intval( $_REQUEST['bulk_emailed_posts'] );
    printf( '<div id="message" class="updated fade">' .
      _n( 'Emailed %s post to Eric.',
        'Emailed %s posts to Eric.',
        $emailed_count,
        'email_to_eric'
      ) . '</div>', $emailed_count );
  }
}
```